# Is it mandatory to use RestTemplate for restful web services? Or it can be ignored while giving @PostMapping with response entity in it?

Tags: rest, web-services, spring-boot, resttemplate

In a previous project I was using rest template to call restful web services method.

But now in the new Project I don't see rest template.We just have `@GetMapping`/`@PostMapping` where we use response entity.

So is it not mandatory to use rest template for restful web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTFM, Buddy ;)

> NOTE: As of 5.0, the non-blocking, reactive
>   org.springframework.web.reactive.client.WebClient offers a modern
>   alternative to the RestTemplate with efficient support for both sync
>   and async, as well as streaming scenarios. The RestTemplate will be
>   deprecated in a future version and will not have major new features
>   added going forward.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html